# 'At a time' or 'in a time'

Tags: phrases, prepositions, time

In the phrase

> The quantity of insects **in/at** a time t is given by i(t).

What is the correct?

Thank you so much!

Comment: _At_ is for points on a line or plane; _in_ is for containers with volumes.

Comment: In mathematical writing, you'd often see, "The quantity of insects at time *t* is given by *i(t)*."  In other words, using *at* without the indefinite article.  This is not really an English question so much as it is a technical writing question - really it depends on the style guide of the publication you're writing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At

In your example “at a time” would refer to a particular moment or an instant in which we want the number of insects.

“In a time” would refer to a duration of time at the end of which we are calculating the number of insects.

I think you mean to use the former version, therefore “at a time” is what is correct according to me.